Getting checked for username instead of email attribute in Identity framework in ASP.NET Core MVC where username is a custom field
I am trying to add a custom input field to my register page of Identity frame in ASP.NET Core MVC.
By default, the AspNetUsers table in the database has a column UserName already it is passed Email given by user.
Register.cshtml.cs:
var user = CreateUser();
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

So the Email and UserName columns both have the same value. But I wanted to have a separate input for UserName. So I added a custom property in input class in Register.cshtml.cs file:
[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserName")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
public string UserName { get; set; }

Now in function OnPostAsync where Email was being set to UserName, I changed it to using UserName value from input instead of Email:
var user = CreateUser();

await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

Now in the database, everything is stored correctly where they are needed to be. UserName column has UserName value which was provided by the user, and Email column has the Email value.
Email is then also confirmed in the next page which is verified from the database.
Now the problem I am facing is in Login page, I have not made any changes in Login.cshtml and Login.cshtml.cs files.
When trying to login, when I provide the Email and Password, I get an error:

Invalid login attempt

Even though I am providing the right credentials. But the twisted part is that when here instead of Email, I provide UserName, the login is successful. But when I check the Login.cshtml.cs file, it is checking for Email, not the UserName.
Login.cshtml.cs:
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }

OnPostAsync method:
ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Email: " + Input.Email);
    Console.WriteLine("Password: " + Input.Password);

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}

I am unable to understand why it is checking the UserName column instead of Email column in the database here.
In this code, it is clearly checking the Email, but in reality it is checking the UserName.
Please guide me through if you can.
I have tried to debug all of these functions and values are being passed correctly. But unable to understand why It is checking the UserName. To my estimation so far, It will check for the field we will pass here in this function:
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);

The answers provided earlier on this Platform are for earlier versions of ASP.NET Core MVC.

.PasswordSignInAsync() takes a string as the first value. It just so happens, that what gets passed to the first field in the login is named Email. Rename this property to PrettyGreenApple and it will work all the same. The names of variables passed into methods do not matter in the slightest.

So, you are saying that Identity will check the UserName field from DB for authentication every time, regardless of the first attribute being passed here to the function PasswordSignInAsync( ). What if we want to change this behavior and we want to check for Email instead of UserName?

Actually, that is not the case. I just gave "Hello world" as the first attribute to the PasswordSignInAsync function and I started getting "Invalid login attempt" Error when trying to login.

I mean, yes, your user is probably not named "Hello world"

Firstly, the PasswordSignInAsync is a built-in method so that we couldn't change it.

So we have 2 options, the first one is continue to use this method but we should use the UserName to query out the userName which should be used inside this method, then we call var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);. I mean that we can add multiple lines of code before this line in login.cshtml.cs to get the Input.Email it required. It will bring benefits that we don't need to add other codes, just like a workaround, but it will bring one more query which shall bring a little bit more pressure in performance.
The second option is that we create our own Login.cshtml method which rewrite the _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync. This might require us to copy and change much more codes, it shall be more scalable and have better performance, but it requires more codes.
This is a normal issue when we use built-in feature, there's not so much space for us to create custom requirement. We can only have some workarounds.
